# How to handle errors in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find out if you can handle if an error occurs in python.

ex:
    if (error code):
        pass

Comment: What kind of error? Improve your question with example of error you want to handle, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `try...except` statement to [handle errors](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). You may choose to skip all errors, but it is highly recommended to be specific about which error you want to handle.

```
#General
try:
    a = 5 / 0
except:
    pass

#Specific
try:
    a = 5 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass

#Multiple errors
try:
    a = 5 / 0
except (ZeroDivisionError, ValueError) as e:
    #Print error code
    print e
```